# Sum Of Two Squares: Where's My Error?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, number-theory

I'm trying to calculate the number of ways to write a natural number as the sum of two squares. I'm working from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function):

[image: specifically]

So, here is my code. Below where I test it, I find what I think is an error in the result.

```
sumOfSquares :: Integer -> Int
sumOfSquares k = 4 * (d1 - d3)
  where
    divs = divisors k
    d1 = congruents d1_test divs
    d3 = congruents d3_test divs
    d1_test n = (n - 1) `mod` 4 == 0
    d3_test n = (n - 3) `mod` 4 == 0

congruents :: (Integer -> Bool) -> [Integer] -> Int
congruents f divs = length $ filter f divs

divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors k = divisors' 2 k
  where
    divisors' n k' | n*n > k' = [k']
                   | n*n == k' = [n, k']
                   | k' `mod` n == 0 = (n:(k' `div` n):result)
                   | otherwise = result
      where result = divisors' (n+1) k'
```

And when I run it, it generates:

```
*Main Numbers.SumOfSquares> sumOfSquares 10
4
```

I calculated that there is only one way to express 10 as a sum of two squares
1^2 + 3^2. Note that the intermediate result `(d1 - d3)` equals 1.

I'm missing something important but don't know what.

Comment: But the formula itself shows that it can only generate multiples of four...

Comment: you have to take into account: (a) we count **tuples**, so **order matters** and (b) **the domain is Z** so negative numbers are valid as well.

Comment: Please don't post formulas or other text as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread the semantics of the formula. The [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function) states the following equation:

[image: cardinality of sum of powers]

There are two important remarks here:

- the domain is **Z**, not **N**, therefore (-1), (-3), 0, etc. are also valid elements for the squares; and
- we count the number of **tuples**, not **sets** so the **order is important** (and (1,2,2) is not equal to (1,2)): if (1,3) is a solution, so is (3,1) and we count these as two separate ones.

Now 10 has the following divisors: **1**, 2, 5, **10** (your program forgot about 1 and 10). Two are congruent with 1 modulo 4: 1 and 5. Furthermore there are no divisors congruent with 3 modulo 4. So `d1 = 2` and `d3 = 0`. Therefore there are eight (4×(2-0) = 8) possibilities:

1. (1,3): 1<sup>2</sup>+3<sup>2</sup>=10
2. (3,1): 3<sup>2</sup>+1<sup>2</sup>=10
3. (1,-3): 1<sup>2</sup>+(-3)<sup>2</sup>=10
4. (3,-1): 3<sup>2</sup>+(-1)<sup>2</sup>=10
5. (-1,3): (-1)<sup>2</sup>+3<sup>2</sup>=10
6. (-3,1): (-3)<sup>2</sup>+1<sup>2</sup>=10
7. (-1,-3): (-1)<sup>2</sup>+(-3)<sup>2</sup>=10
8. (-3,-1): (-3)<sup>2</sup>+(-1)<sup>2</sup>=10

Now we only have to resolve the issue with your program. You simply need to start counting from `1` instead of `2`:

```
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors k = divisors' 1
  where
    divisors' i | i2 > k = []
                | i2 == k = [i]
                | k `mod` i == 0 = (i:(k `div` i):result)
                | otherwise = result
      where i2 = i*i
            result = divisors' (i+1)
```

I also simplified the program a bit and solved some other semantical errors. Now it should at least be sound with *r<sub>k</sub>(n)*.

Comment: divisors 10 == []. hmm

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: fixed; swapped `k` and `i`.